# How to fix "loading model for blockstate variant '#normal' exception" in minecraft forge?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

After succesfully making an item have a texture, for the last hours I am struggling to make the texture loading work for blocks (Interpreting my error message, it's the model loading I struggle with)

I followed cubicoders tutorial ( https://cubicoder.wordpress.com/2018/06/20/basic-block/ ) for the progress so far. Because his solution for creating blocks threw an error, I checked back with other tutorials. While my error log insists the problem lies within the model loading (spezifically the variant loading of the variant #normal), this part is the exact same as in every tutorial I could find.
What else could be the trigger for such an exception?

My complete project code can be found here: https://github.com/harlekintiger/modding
It's really just the basic setup, one item and this broken block.

---

The most important parts are the following:

"basic_block.json" located in "resources/assets/MODID/blockstate":

```
{
   "forge_marker": 1,
   "defaults": {
      "model": "firstforgemod:basic_block"
   },
      "variants": {
         "normal": [{}],
         "inventory": [{}]
   }
}
```

"basic_block.json" located in "resources/assets/MODID/models/block":

```
{
   "parent": "block/cube_all",
   "textures": {
      "all": "firstforgemod:blocks/basic_block"
   }
}
```

Class of the actual block:

```
public class BlockBasic extends Block{

    public BlockBasic(Material material, String unlocalizedName, String registryName){
        this(material, SoundType.STONE, unlocalizedName, registryName);
    }

    public BlockBasic(Material material, SoundType sound, String unlocalizedName, String registryName){
        super(material);
        setUnlocalizedName(FirstForgeMod.MODID + "." + unlocalizedName);
        setRegistryName(registryName);
        setCreativeTab(FirstForgeMod.TUTORIAL_TAB);
        setSoundType(sound);
    }
}
```

Class to collect the blocks:

```
@ObjectHolder(FirstForgeMod.MODID)
public class TutorialBlocks {

    public static final Block BASIC_BLOCK = null;
}
```

ModelRegistryHandler class:     (my guess is there is something missing in here)

```
@EventBusSubscriber(Side.CLIENT)
public class ModelRegistryHandler {

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerModels(ModelRegistryEvent event){
        registerModel(TutorialItems.BASIC_ITEM);
        registerModel(Item.getItemFromBlock(TutorialBlocks.BASIC_BLOCK));
    }

    private static void registerModel(Item item) {
        ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(item.getRegistryName(), "inventory"));
    }
}
```

RegistryHandler class:

```
@EventBusSubscriber
public class RegistryHandler {

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerBlocks(Register<Block> event){
        final Block[] blocks ={
            new BlockBasic(Material.ROCK, "blockBasic", "basic_block")
        };

        event.getRegistry().registerAll(blocks);
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public  static  void registerItems(Register<Item> event){
        final Item[] items = {
                new ItemBasic("itemBasic", "basic_item")
        };

        final Item[] itemBlocks = {
                new ItemBlock(TutorialBlocks.BASIC_BLOCK).setRegistryName(TutorialBlocks.BASIC_BLOCK.getRegistryName())
        };

        event.getRegistry().registerAll(items);
        event.getRegistry().registerAll(itemBlocks);
    }
}
```

Log file of minecraft starting (with the error message) and closing:
https://pastebin.com/Ff7NuFSk

---

What I am getting:
The game starts and in-game the block can be placed, but is completely untextured (missing textures texutre) in both the world and the inventory.

Comment: Can you post the complete log file? Use pastebin if you have to. "Cannot load model" is a very broad error and down underneath it will be *another* error (the true source) that will have more information.

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for the suggestion, I did add the log file

Comment: Just to be complete, Cubicoder (the tutorial author) found I wrote "blockstate" instead of "blockstates" as the folder name. So quadruple check your spelling if you have the same error. If it persists, look at Draco18s answer, it is worth its character count in kilos of gold!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 14 column 2 path $
```

There's your underlying error.

https://github.com/harlekintiger/modding/blob/master/src/main/resources/assets/firstforgemod/blockstates/basic_block.json#L14

JSON is a data format, it doesn't allow comments (of any type) anywhere in the file.

Comment: You have some serious error message analytic skills!
It now works like a charm, thank you very much :)

Comment: @harlekintiger Its because I've been working with the system long enough to know what to look for. "Error loading model" is an error thrown by one system in response to any one of a half dozen or so errors through by *one or more other systems.* Error in the JSON itself, missing blockstate file, a missing model file, a missing texture file, a missing blockstate entry (i.e. you said "I have a block with facing" and then your blockstate doesn't have all of the facing directions), etc.